# Reset git template path

Tags: git, github

I am trying to set git template path as :

```
– git config --global commit.template  <path to template>
```

For the very first attempt i enter wrong path and cannot reset the path again i am getting below error :

```
warning: commit.template has multiple values
error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
       Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change commit.template.
```

Hence I am not able to do `git commit`.

**Edit :**

Initally i executed :

```
– git config --global commit.template  E:/mygit
```

where my git is just folder and i forgot to mention file name

Next time i executed :

[image]

Any pointer to my query would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove it using the following:

```
git config --global --unset-all commit.template
```

I'm not sure how you ended up with multiple values in there. When I call `git config commit.template foo.txt`, it overwrites the previous value.

The only way I could reproduce your issue was by using `git config --add commit.template foo.txt`, which seems to add a second value.

If you don't want to use command line, you can also edit your global git configuration file with a text editor. It probably includes a section like the following:

```
[commit]
    template = template2.txt
    template = template.txt
```

Comment: Can you update your question to show what you did (the exact command) and then also the output of that command?

Comment: Can you try the `--unset-all` command from my answer, @diva? What happens when you execute that? It should remove all values for that key, and then you should be able to set it again.

Comment: You're welcome. The `-all` is indeed important, as it will remove all values, not just a single one.

Comment: yup got the idea another solution is also worked using replace-all